# Building a site with susy sass

Tags: susy-sass

I'm looking at using susy sass to build an entire website, as opposed to bootstrap. Am I right in saying that the site has to be built page per pge. I mean if say on the home the aside tag as 3 columns and on the about page the aside tag has 4 columns you'd have to write this style for each page? I don't seem to find good referencws for building a whole site with susy.

Thanks

Comment: Susy is just a tool to help write CSS, and it has almost no opinions about how you do that. Susy will have exactly the same constraints as writing the CSS yourself. If you want things to look different on each page, you will have to specify that somehow, but CSS is also good at handling global styles. It's up to you, and your specific needs!

Comment: Thanks, for that, but would it need a stylesheet for each page then? Is this the best practice? @MiriamEricSuzanne

Comment: No, best practice is to use one stylesheet for an entire website or app.

Comment: @MiriamEricSuzanne sorry what I meant was, when building it you'd need to style page per page, as opposed to bootstrap where you have all the grid styles written out, eg. col-md-2 all these grid styles would have to be done per page in susy right?

Comment: No, with Susy you can do anything you want. You can build bootstrap with Susy, if you want to - or your own version of something like bootstrap. You can also style component-by-component, or page-by-page, or any way you like. Susy isn't one grid system — it's a math engine that you can use to build your own system.